# capture link text and append to the URL as query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

I want to capture the text that is in between anchor link tag and pass it to the href value as query string so it looks like http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?cat=cancer

The reason I can't add that manually is because the value in between  and  is dynamic. How do I capture that and append to the url using jquery or javascript??

or i can maybe, at the event of Cancer link being clicked, direct it to http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?cat=cancer

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?cat="> Cancer</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = this.href + $.trim($(this).text());
});
```

Or you could replace the `href` attribute for each link:

```
$("a").prop("href", function () {
    return this.href += $.trim($(this).text());
});
```

Then clicking each link will automatically direct the user correctly. Your selector (`$("a")` should be more specific, depending on your markup)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6U749/

**Edit:** If you have to do it inline, here's one way:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?cat=" onclick="window.location.href = this.href + $.trim($(this).text());"> Cancer</a>
```

Comment: thank you. I want to add onclick event right on the link itself like this: (a tag  HREF value onclick Take me to HREF value+LinkText)(close a tag)

Comment: @AnjuThapa: The second method should accomplish that. Consider completely separating your markup (HTML) from your behavior (JavaScript) for more maintainable code.

Comment: I know what u mean, but I am on XSL file Like this :  onClick="location.href='http://mysite.com/events/Pages/test1.aspx?kwd='+ document.getElementById('EventSearchBox').value;

Comment: For this time being, can you show me how you would achieve same thing inline?? give id to the link and getelemendbyid on it and get its value?

Comment: @AnjuThapa: Sure, I understand your problem now.

Comment: Not working ...the value-of select would be the link text when it finally renders html ..<a href="http://mysite.com/events/SitePages/test1.aspx?cat=" onclick="window.location.href = this.href + $.trim($(this).text());">
<xsl:value-of select="@Event_x0020_Category" /></a>

Comment: What happens when you click the link? I'm not sure I can help you much further I don't know XSL.

Comment: It just grabs the original href value without the link text..Yea I am a little weak on Jquery side.. Can we do this?   : -onClick="location.href='http://mysite.com/events/SitePages/test1.aspx?kwd='+ THE LINK TEXT

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.someClassImStickingOnLinksThatNeedThisBehavior').each(function()
{
    this.href = $.trim(this.href) + $.trim(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Then, for any link, it would automatically update the HREF to the current HREF plus the value of the node.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var yourlink = $("#youlink");
var href = yourlink.attr("href");
var text = yourlink.html();

yourlink.attr("href", href + "?cat=" + text);
```